# Using IFNULL in sqlalchemy core

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use sqlalchemy core select rows from a `mysql` table using `IFNULL`.

Given a table like so:

```
id    int1    string1   other
1      7        NULL    other stuff
2      NULL     bar     more stuff
```

The sql would be something like:

```
SELECT IFNULL(int1, 0) AS int1, IFNULL(string1, '') AS string1 FROM table
```

Is this possible using the core? What would be great would be something like

```
s = select(ifnull(table.c.int1, 0), ifnull(table.c.string1, ''))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to use func from sqlalchemy.sql like this for arbitrary database functions (I think ifnull is db dependent, I use coalesce for postgresql):

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, func
# assuming you have imported table from somewhere!!


s = select([func.ifnull(table.c.int1, 0), func.ifnull(table.c.string1, '')])
```

Comment: What version are you using? I'm using SQLAlchemy==1.0.5 and I think func has been there since 0.4 at least.

Answer (score 19):

PostgreSQL doesn't support if null

instead of ifnull() you can use func.coalesce()

Syntax -

```
  func.coalesce(Table.field, default_value)
```

Example -

```
 func.coalesce(Order.price, 0)

 func.coalesce(Student.name, ' ')
```